# AttributeError: module 'selenium' has no attribute 'webdriver' using Selenium webdriver through PyCharm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, anaconda

I have Pycharm with Anaconda as my interpreter. Selenium is successfully installed and its webdriver is accessible when I use Jupyter Notebook but when I try to run the same code in PyCharm, It says :
**AttributeError: module 'selenium' has no attribute 'webdriver'**
As shown in here:
[image: PyCharm not detecting selenium webdriver]

I have checked my project interpreter settings and Selenium appears in the list as in here:
[image: Selenium appears to be installed in PyCharm]

Then I clicked on Selenium to reveal this window and installed it as was suggested:
[image: install selenium]
[image: selenium installed]
PyCharm does it indexing after this. For a while there appears no red line under webdriver import but on running the file I get the sae old message saying:
**AttributeError: module 'selenium' has no attribute 'webdriver'**

By the way I have also tried to use alt+Enter and it installs the package but to no benefit. It always remain so.
The same issue is in Spyder. webdriver is not being accessible there as well.
I have done it like a zillion times with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using *Python*'s *Selenium* module you shouldn't use **selenium** as a filename or user defined variable as it is a keyword / reserved word. Using so can create [**`Circular dependency`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency).

### Solution

Rename the filename from `selenium.py` to **`mySelenium.py`** and execute your test.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the file name, use `run.py` or other file name instead of `selenium.py`.

Comment: this is not an answer, but a comment: it doesn't explain why this problem arose and how to deal with it in the future